# Find element that appears after a specific element in a separate <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium-rc

I first use this code to find an element with a specific text content:

```
$('someElement').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == 'Some text';
});
```

Then, I want to find the `<input>` element that's inside the next `<td>` tag.

Below is the HTML code:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="SH_Request_First_Name">
            First name <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="text" name="SH_Request_First_Name" id="SH_Request_First_Name"
        value="" size="38" maxlength="50" onchange="validatePresent(this, 'SH_Request_First_Name_Note');"
        /> <span id="SH_Request_First_Name_Note">&nbsp;</span>

    </td>
</tr>
```

I first found the label with text "First name".  Then I want to find the `<input>` that's in the next `<td>` tag.

Is it possible to do the above tasks in JavaScript, instead of jQuery?

Comment: If you are already using the jQuery library then stick with it for cross-browser compatibility. Unless you are planning to completely get rid of jQuery in your app.

Comment: No, I haven't been using jQuery in the program I want to write.  I am trying to automate a test scenario using Selenium RC, and am not sure if it supports jQuery.  Thanks.

Comment: Ah I see. That makes sense. In our selenium tests for our C# application we are using CSS selectors as jQuery selectors are not known to selenium as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

When you've found the first td tag you can access the next one in JS with

```
yourTd.nextSibling
```

This will return the next tag in the document.

If you want to get there from the label you first have to get the parent and then the sibling:

```
yourLabel.parentElement.nextSibling
```

but this construct is error prone if you change the HTML construct some times. I would recommend to use jQuery and select by a specidic css class or something like that, so it doesn't have to be exactly the next element, only one of the next elements with that css class.

Comment: Thanks, however, I am not trying to find the next td tag.  The next element that I want to find is not a sibling of the first element.

Comment: @user1020173: You said you want the input in the next td tag. The next td tag is the sibling of the td tag you are currently in. Unless your posted code is incorrect.

Comment: Well, actually, first I found the label tag within the first td tag.  Then I want to find the input tag within the next td tag.  I would think the label tag and the input tag aren't siblings.  Sorry, I am new to these concepts.

Comment: @user1020173: No worries, the td tags are siblings. So you find the td tag with the matching label, then go to the td's sibling to get the input from it.